Matrix and analysis of a priori contrasts in R for an interaction
I have been stuck on a problem for days, and although I have searched in the forum, I have not been able to find the solution. I have the following similar dataset
blocks <- rep(1:3, each = 17) 
treatments <- rep(c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 4), 
                    rep("D", 3), rep("E", 4)), times = 3)
Y <- runif(51, min = 0, max = 1)
data <- data.frame(Y = Y, Block = factor(blocks), 
                   Treatments = factor(treatments))
table(data$Block,data$Treatments)

I am testing if treatments are statistically different from each other within and between blocks using the following model:
glmmTMB(y=block*treatments, family=beta_family(link="logit"), 
           data=data)

However, I am not interested in the comparison between all treatments within and between blocks but I have precise hypotheses to test that are:
Within each Block:
treatments B vs. C vs. E,  A vs. B,  C vs. D
Between blocks
treatments A, B, C, E (i.e. A in block 1 vs A in block 2 vs A in block 3).
Having clear test to perform I tried to apply "priori contrasts". I formed a matrix for the treatments defined as follows:
C vs E <- c(0,0,-1,0,1)
B vs E <- c(0,-1,0,0,1) # C vs B should be implicit
A vs B <- c(1,-1,0,0,0)
C vs D <- c(0,0,1,-1,0)
contrs <- cbind(C vs E, B vs E, A vs B, C vs D)
contrasts(data$treatment) <- contrs

at this point I got stuck. I cannot figure out how to formulate the matrix for Block to perform the interactions and to obtain the contrasts that I am interested. I saw that it is possible to use the emmeans package by doing the contrasts a posteriori but I think it is necessary to do a pairwise comparison and then select the contrasts I am interested from emmeans summary but I would like to avoid that as I read that it is not a correct practice when I have defined research questions.
I would like to ask if the idea of using the "a priori" contrasts is correct or if I am completely wrong, if I set the contrasts correctly and how I could get the statistical difference between the contrasts that I am interested.
